# HP ML310 G8v2 server hangs after memory upgrade

Tags: hp-proliant

I bought the HP Proliant ML310 G8v2 server with 4GB of  RAM.  I also bought the memory module HP 8GB (1x8GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3L-10600R-9-10.E1 1333 ECC. When I plugged this memory into the server. the server stops with initializing at 20%.

I take a look at www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=​c04111535 and I think this memory modules must been supported.

Someone an idea why this memory module is not working?

Best regards, Wim

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the memory was plugged in?  Did you simply add the additional memory alongside the original memory or swap it?  Was the same slot used, etc?

Comment: I replaced the 4GB for the new one 8 GB. I used the same slot, but tried also the other ones. I have also tried another 8GB memory module.

Answer (score 0):

With the upgraded memory you may need to check that the memory speed settings are correct in BIOS.  I would imagine that it is set to auto-detect the appropriate speed, but you may try setting it to the appropriate speed there.

You could also try running [memtest](http://www.memtest.org), which is included with most OS distributions and/or rescue disks.  It should be possible to insert a bootable USB, CD or DVD that contains memtest, then at the boot selection menu select memtest.  There are several guides available for making bootable memtest images and analyzing the results that can be found be doing a * search.

Downloads for bootable memtest86 images can be found on the [memtest86.com website](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) and should have the latests versions available.  It should be noted that other memory testing and diagnostic tools are available.

*insert favorite search engine here

Comment: It is not possible to configure the BIOS. With the upgrade memory the server gives an error beep... the server reboots and the screen is black.